# Apache Tomcat 8.5.11 on Windows - Service wouldn't start - The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: windows, tomcat

I just deployed (unzip file) Apache Tomcat 8.5.11 and for some reason it would not start.

Here is what I checked:

1. The command `dir %JAVA_HOME%` shows the contents of the correct folder,
2. The command `dir %JRE_HOME%` shows the contents of the correct folder,
3. The command `dir %CATALINA_HOME%` shows the contents of the correct folder.

**Note**: Initially, I defined these environment variables like:

```
SET CATALINA_HOME=C:\Program Files\TC_Install
```

but it didn't work (I mean, the `DIR` command returned an error. Then, I used:

```
SET CATALINA_HOME="C:\Program Files\TC_Install"
```

and this one did work for the `DIR` command but not for the problem presented in this question.

Things I tried:

1. User the command `start.bat` --> Service would not start,
2. Manually attempt to start the service --> Service would not start,
3. Manually tried to execute the program `tomcat8.exe` --> A DOS window opens for a fraction of a second and that's it.

I don't succeed to figure out what the error message refers to (i.e. which file cannot find).

### Edit

I made a few more checks:

Now, when I run the command `startup.bat`, I get the following error:

```
DOCUMENTS\MyDir\MySW\apache-tomcat-8.5.11"" was unexpected at this time.
```

which obviously misses "`H:\MY`" at the left.

I re-defined the values of CATALINA_HOME, JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME like:

```
SET CATALINA_HOME=H:\MY DOCUMENTS\MyDir\MySW\apache-tomcat-8.5.11
```

(i.e. without the `"` wrapping) and the error disappeared, but still no positive result about the service.

I also added some `echo` lines within the CATALINA.BAT script to show the values of the command and parameters, getting:

```
Command parameter: _EXECJAVA         start "Tomcat8" "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe"
Command parameter: LOGGING_CONFIG    -Djava.util.logging.config.file="H:\MY DOCUMENTS\MyDir\MySW\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\conf\logging.properties"
Command parameter: LOGGING_MANAGER   -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager"
Command parameter: JAVA_OPTS          "-Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048" -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
Command parameter: CATALINA_OPTS     
Command parameter: DEBUG_OPTS        
Command parameter: CLASSPATH         H:\MY DOCUMENTS\MyDir\MySW\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\bin\bootstrap.jar;H:\MY DOCUMENTS\MyDir\MySW\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\bin\tomcat-juli.jar
Command parameter: CATALINA_BASE     H:\MY DOCUMENTS\MyDir\MySW\apache-tomcat-8.5.11
Command parameter: CATALINA_HOME     H:\MY DOCUMENTS\MyDir\MySW\apache-tomcat-8.5.11
Command parameter: CATALINA_TMPDIR   H:\MY DOCUMENTS\MyDir\MySW\apache-tomcat-8.5.11\temp
Command parameter: MAINCLASS         org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap"
Command parameter: CMD_LINE_ARGS     
Command parameter: ACTION            start
```

Comment: Hi,
It will be helpful, If you Can provide any event viewer log and any other logs where any message is logged

Comment: Hello @visrey and thanks for your reply. Actually, the logs do not show anything in particular. For instance, I try the command `startup.bat` which causes no additions to any log. Also, the event viewer does not show anything that may give a hint (i.e. no errors at all). I added some information to the question that might be of help.

Comment: @visrey Forgot one (possibly) important detail: The Server I'm trying to run Tomcat does not have a direct connection to the Internet (company policy).

Comment: Hi FDavidov,
I doubt the problem is with the folder structure.
Can you please copy your tomcat from "H:\MY DOCUMENTS\MyDir\MySW\apache-tomcat-8.5.11" to the folder "H:\apache-tomcat-8.5.11"

Comment: Thank you @visrey for your response. It turned out that, though I was defined by the system guys as the "ADMINISTRATOR" of the server, I was in fact a sort of MINI-ADMINISTRATOR. They change my privileges, I switched to the Wizard installation in Windows (the same for me), and now I have TOMCAT up and running. Many thanks for the time you took to address my issue and for trying to assist.